# How to detect special characters and numbers in a string?

Tags: c#, string, character

Does anyone have an idea on how to detect special characters in a string via an if statement?

I need the output to look something like this:

```
Enter Name: Johnson!
INVALID INPUT TRY AGAIN.
Enter Name: Johnson
ACCEPTED INPUT.
```

Is there any way to do that with only using.System ?

Comment: Put some more test cases here. Because if your case is too complex, `regex` is the best option for you. If you just want to check for `!`, then `string.contains` will do fine.

Answer (score 1):

As your question is not very clear,
try this, if you want to check one of some specified characters are exist in your string `input`

```
var specialChars = new[] {"!", ":", ",", "/", "1"}; //add some or more characters or numbers as into this string array
var result = specialChars.Any(input.Contains)
```